# Linear Functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am stuck along the way while trying to prove that there exists a nonzero functional $f$ on $V$ such that $T^tf=cf$ for any scalar $c$ and a nonzero $\alpha\in V$ s.t. $T(\alpha)=c\alpha$. Where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$.

Here is how I start:

Let $dimV=n$. Let $B=\{\alpha,\alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{n}\}$ be the basis for $V$ and $B^*=\{f,f_{2},...,f_{n}\}$ be the dual basis.

Then for $v\in V$,

$v=f(v)\alpha + \sum_{k=2}^{n}{f_k(v)\alpha_k}$. Then we have

$(T^tf)(v)=f(Tv)$.........

If I am moving in the right direction, please I need to know how to finish it up, otherwise, what should I do?